# How does faster-than-light travel work in the Metroid universe?

Tags: ftl-drive, metroid

I'm a big fan of the Metroid prime games. I was reading about the technology in that universe and found I couldn't find anything on how they achieve faster than light travel. Is there anything saying or even hinting on the method in the games or mangas that I just haven't found?

Comment: No left or right...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official manga](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=4094) and [comics](https://metroid.fandom.com/wiki/Nintendo_Comics_System) are very terse on the subject of space travel (and the translation provided is shaky at best) but we do learn that ships...

> 'jump'

...through

> 'hyperspace'

(which apparently exists outside of our normal three dimensions), in order to travel between star systems and even extra-galactically on occasion.

> [image]

This transit isn't instantaneous, and different ships travel at differing speeds. Federation 'recon' ships are evidently substantially faster than those from less-developed races.

> [image]

Ships tend to have large engines that [emit a bright plume when in motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEsDf5PAc-4&t=87s), but it's not clear whether this is involved in FTL travel, or just intrasystem travel (e.g. after FTL travel has concluded).

> [image]

Apparently a particular substance, referred to as Afloraltite, is involved in space travel and used extensively by Federation 'caravans' carrying food and other goods around the member planets. This presumably is a fuel source since it needs to be renewed constantly. There's no indication of whether this substance is needed for FTL travel.

> [image]

---

We also have a diagram of Samus' ship from the [*Captain Nintendo*](https://metroid.fandom.com/wiki/Nintendo_Comics_System) comics. These show that her ship has separate drive systems for atmospheric, sublight, and hyperspace flight.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot more than I've been able to find.

Comment: @AaronAbel - I'm just having a look at some of the comics now. They don't really go into any detail. The wiki mentions a prototype ship "jumping" to another galaxy. I'm trying to track that one down

Comment: An "engine room"; https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/metroid/images/c/ce/Engineroom.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20081009231818